# Foreign person forgot to turn in W8-BEN

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-8-ben, foreign

I am a foreign person living abroad. I own stocks with a US brokerage. I do not have SSN or ITIN. Last year, I forgot to submit W8-BEN. My brokerage did 24% W9 withholding on the dividends and gave me a 1099.

I have several questions:

1. Do I have to file a tax return for last year?
2. How can I get the withheld money back?
3. How can I file a return without ITIN/SSN?

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. 24% is the backup withholding for 'resident' tax (really resident _or_ citizen/LPR, but you are neither). If you have a foreign address and didn't provide an SSN, they should assume you are NRA (as you indeed are) and the default (non-treaty) withholding should be 30% and reported on 1042-S.

Comment: I verified and it was indeed 24% W9 withholding. Maybe because I didn't file W8-BEN, they automatically assumed I was "resident." Yes, I provided a foreign address and did/do not live in US.

Comment: That would be the reason why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to file a tax return for last year?

Not if you don't care about this money.

> How can I get the withheld money back?

By filing a [non-resident tax return](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1040-nr) and showing how much you really should have paid. The 24% is the backup withholding rate, which is charged in your case because you [failed to provide W9/W8](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/backup-withholding). The NR tax rate is flat 30%, but [tax treaties](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/united-states-income-tax-treaties-a-to-z) may affect you and your actual tax rate (especially for dividends) may be much lower, depending on the treaty. Also, if you want to claim credit in your home country for the tax paid in the US - you'd probably need to provide a US tax return filed with the IRS, the 1099 withholding are not an evidence of actual tax liability assessed.

> How can I file a return without ITIN/SSN?

You file a [form W7](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-w-7) with the return (read through the instructions [here](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/iw7) and [here](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#en_US_2021_publink24811vd0e2872))

Comment: In my particular case, there is a treaty and 24% is higher than what should have been withheld.

Comment: Is it possible to point me to some official reference that states there is no need to file a return if I don't care about the money? (It is a tiny amount.) Thanks.

Comment: @ml-guy sure, here: https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040nr#en_US_2021_publink100057473.